# Saving properties android error

Tags: android, properties, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to save some properties and print them out, but it doesn't work for some reason. Here's the code.
My intention is to make a file that contains passwords and usernames, as pairs. And then later on I'm going to iterate through them.
Is there an easier/better way to do this?

```
public void createUser(){

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try{
        fileOutputStream = context.openFileOutput("Testfile", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        properties.setProperty("username", "password");
        properties.store(fileOutputStream, "User created");
        fileOutputStream.close();

    } catch(IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error create", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

And then I'm trying to print them out:

```
public void printUser( TextView textView){

    File infoFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "TestFile");
    BufferedReader br;
    try{
        br = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(infoFile));
        properties.load(br);
        textView.setText(properties.getProperty("username"));

    } catch(IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error printing users", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

But nothing happens. I did basically the same in eclipse with JSwing and it worked well there.

Comment: Why not use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)?

Comment: @MoraisIgor I'm not familiar with that....I think I will stick with properties for now.

Comment: Shared Preferences is the most common way to save simple data, see these examples: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm).

Comment: Look at [it](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) too.